# Magento: translations in emails template not working

Tags: email, magento, translation

It seems to be translation in Abandoned Cart Emails (Template master) is not working.

1. When I try to add product to cart, I have special rule, which sends email to user.
2. In template of this email I have like this:

> {{block
>   type="tm_abandoned/checkout_cart_totals" quote="$quote"
>   history="$history" template="tm/abandoned/email/items/totals.phtml"}}

3. Template `totals.phtml` call rewrited `renderTotals()`.
4. In English version - all OK, I see english words in totals block,which is OK.
5. But in German version I see English version again, despite of this `de_DE` locale is there and translation's csv is provided.

No idea what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSV Translation will not work for email templates. Just copy all of the email templates from en_us to your locale (de_DE) then translate templates as per your needs. Also keep in mind that dynamic variable which are coming from php code will automatically be translated by csv. 
Thanks.